# Получение данных для другой (неактивной в данный момент) активити

Tags: java, android

Есть приложение по сути подобное мессенджерам.
Есть несколько активити: LoginActivity, MainActivity, ChatDetailsActivity.

Подскажите каким образом реализовывается возможность получения уведомлений (какой-то сигнал) о том, что было получено новое сообщение в некотором чате в тот момент когда пользователь переписывается в другом чате?